# What should I do about comments like this?

Tags: support, comments

I have just received [this comment](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/149181/what-do-i-need-to-destroy-the-world#comment364812_149181):

> Are you sure you didn't mean to post this to Worldbuilding or Arquade?

Those might make sense based on the *title* of the question, but even skimming it should make it obvious that there is no way, ever, that it's going to be on-topic for either of those sites.

I've already replied to them explaining why it is on PPCG, but is there something else that I should do here?

Comment: Seems like a question for PP&CG Meta? Different sites have various policies about this sort of thing.

Comment: @Catija maybe… I wasn't sure where because the comment is recommending terrible migrations. (Also, it's usually abbreviated PPCG—no ampersand.)

Comment: I think it was a joke...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Flag it

Flag the comment as "no longer needed". The mods should be able to see that the recommendation for migration is poor. If they don't, flag with a custom reason and explain... or start with the custom reason if you'd rather cut to the chase.

### Respond to the comment

Kindly... Tell them that the question is not appropriate for either of those sites. Explain why.

### Nothing

If it's really a bad suggestion, there's likely no reason to even bother with it. Ignore it and move on.

Comment: to add to that - Personally I'm a fan of "If you think it should be migrated, you should do the necessary" - VTCing for a standard site. Flagging otherwise. These comments are just noise.